# Oracle: How do I get the list of columns in a *Materialized* VIEW?

Tags: oracle

It looks like we have two objects in our database that have the same name, 'X'. One is a Materialized View and the other is a table. I believe that the MV came first and then the developers switched over to using traditional table type object. In our db, I see that the definition of the MV matches the columns of the table.

When I perform the following query

select * from all_tab_columns c where c.TABLE_NAME = 'X' order by C.COLUMN_ID;

I get a SINGLE list of columns. I assume that I am getting the list of all of the columns in the table, not the materialized view, which could contain different columns than the table of the same name but in my case, as already mentioned, the columns in each happen to match.

I guess that I expected that both sets of columns, a set for the MV and a set of columns for the table, would be returned from the ALL_TAB_COLUMNS view and that they would be separated by a field that stored the TYPE of the parent, for example PARENT_OBJECT_TYPE = 'MATERIALIZED VIEW' or PARENT_OBJECT_TYPE = 'TABLE' and that this would be part of the key to the ALL_OBJECTS table (OWNER, OBJECT_NAME, OBJECT_TYPE) but this is not the case.

How do I get the list of columns in a *Materialized* VIEW? Or is my assumption wrong that it is not possible to have two different sets columns for two objects with the same name, one being an MV and the other being a TABLE? I am unable to create objects in the database to test the latter case.

Comment: Did you check ALL_MVIEWS.QUERY  column?

Comment: After reading @Littlefoot's excellent answer, please check also the columns `MVIEW_NAME` and `CONTAINER_NAME` of the view 'ALL_MVIEWS'. The first one is the name of your materialized view, the second on of the underlying table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got those columns already. This is how Oracle sets it up.

Here's an example:

There's no object named `LF` in my schema:

```
SQL> select object_name, object_type from user_objects where object_name = 'LF';

no rows selected
```

I'll create a materialized view:

```
SQL> create materialized view lf as select * From dept;

Materialized view created.
```

What do I have?

```
SQL> select object_name, object_type from user_objects where object_name = 'LF';

OBJECT_NAME                    OBJECT_TYPE
------------------------------ -------------------
LF                             TABLE
LF                             MATERIALIZED VIEW

SQL>
```

See? A table, and a materialized view. Why? Because Oracle uses

- table to actually *store* data (as materialized views do have data, unlike "ordinary" views which are just stored queries)
- materialized view, which contains info about *refreshing* options

So, when you queried `all_tab_columns`, you did get what you asked for:

```
SQL> select column_name, data_type from user_tab_columns where table_name = 'LF';

COLUMN_NAME                    DATA_TYPE
------------------------------ --------------------
DEPTNO                         NUMBER
DNAME                          VARCHAR2
LOC                            VARCHAR2

SQL>
```

---

A little bit about prebuilt table:

Dropping the old MV first:

```
SQL> drop materialized view lf;

Materialized view dropped.
```

Create a table which will be used as a "target" of the materialized view's query; it'll hold data:

```
SQL> create table lf as select * From dept where 1 = 2;

Table created.

SQL> select * From lf;

no rows selected
```

Use `on prebuilt table` option:

```
SQL> create materialized view lf on prebuilt table
  2  as select * From dept;

Materialized view created.

SQL> select * From lf;

no rows selected
```

Empty; refresh it (*on demand*, right?):

```
SQL> exec dbms_mview.refresh('LF');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * From lf;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON

SQL>
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, the table is the underlying table that the materialized view stored the results of the view query. I knew that with an MV, the difference data was materialized to a table but I didn't think that that table name was exposed with a table object that was always the same as the MV. I thought it was hidden an accessible only via  the MV name. So, then you cannot have a MV and a TABLE with a different set of columns, right?

Comment: And I presume that if you try to create a MV with name 'X" , you'd get an error message if a table with name X already existed, because Oracle would want to create a counterpart table X when the MV was created? Am I following or totally misinterpreting?

Comment: You cannot have a MV and a TABLE with a different set of columns. If you tried to create a MV with name "X" and if table "X" existed, you would **not** get an error if you used the **on prebuilt table** option. Otherwise, you would. I added an example; have a look.

Comment: Correction (if it matters): as materialized view can be created on a join of several tables, then its (MV's) column list may, and usually does, differ from list of column in all source tables.

Comment: @Littlefoot Very well explained!